# C# Using the web browser in a Windows Forms Application- ambiguity between variables

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, compiler-errors

I am working on a booking system that has been written in C#, having not looked at C# for about 5/6 years. At the moment, the code runs a standalone application (i.e. the booking system runs in its own Windows Forms Application window).

My intention is to embed the functionality provided by the existing application inside a web browser- effectively, I want to add a web browser to the application, and then run the features that are currently provided from inside that web browser.

Looking through the code, I can see that it already has a browser feature there, which is not being utilized at the moment- so I am looking to use that.

However, when I try to create/ use an instance of the browser, I get a compile error that says:

> Ambiguity between 'MainWindow.mBrowse' and 'MainWindow.mBrowse'

The code where I am trying to use it is:

```
namespace RAgent{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window{
        ...
        RBrowser mBrowse;
        ...
        public MainWindow(){
            ...
            mBrowse.Browser_Load(...)
            ...
        }
    ...
    }
...
}
```

The `Browser_Load()` function is defined in `RBrowser.cs`:

```
namespace RAgent{
    public partial class RBrowser : Form{
        public RBrowser(){
            ...
        }
        void Browser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

Can anyone explain to me what this compile error means, and how I can resolve it?

Comment: what does the other definition of the partial `MainWindow` look like? does that also declare a `mBrowse` member?

Comment: This is where my unfamiliarity with C# comes in- I've never used partial classes before. It seems that the other definition comes in the development of the GUI for the application- in some auto-generated code in a `.xaml` file, where the first line is: `<Window x: Class="RiviamAgent.MainWindow"`. There are then a lot of tags that look very similar to HTML, which are being used to create and display the GUI of the standalone application that I want to incorporate into a browser.

Comment: @someone2088 this is weird, because you said this problem occurred in a Windows Forms project, but you are mentioning `.xaml` file which is a not a WinForm term. Is this a WinForm project or a WPF/UWP project?

Comment: ...and you mustn't declare `mBrowse` in your code-behind (`MainWindow`) class, because it is already declared for you automatically , as long as you name something as `mBrowse` in the form designer.

Comment: Apologies- it's a WPF application (I think), using the .NET Framework 4.5, and the output type is 'Windows Application'

Comment: The form designer being the graphical representation with the XAML markup? This is something I have never used before- I have always written the code for the GUI inside the source itself (having mainly used Java for applications requiring a GUI previously)

Comment: No, `MainWindow.xaml` doesn't reference `mBrowse` at all- the only place I've seen it is where it's declared in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`...